# Does laravel Event::queue() works in local environment?

Tags: php, events, laravel, laravel-4, observers

Does **Event::queue('event.name')** works in local environment?

Provided that it works locally, as I understand we still have to flush the event using **Event::flush('event.name')**. But I am not able to make it work. The usual **Event::fire('event.name')** works just fine.

This is my controller store method

```
public function store(){
            $input = Input::all();
            if ($this->validator->isValidForCreation($input)){
                $owner = $this->admin->createOwner($input);
                Event::queue('event.name', [$input]);
                return Redirect::route('admin.index')->with('success', 'Owner successfully created.');
            }
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->validator->getErrors());
        }
```

Where should I use the Event::flush('event.name') in my code? I tried flushing it in a route closure (just for testing) after storing the user, but it didn't trigger the event and the code inside the event handler wasn't executed. Should I flush it inside the store function before redirecting to other route?

Comment: Where you call the `Event::flush` method depends on what you are trying to acheive. Provide some more details, such as why do you need the event to be queued?

Comment: Well, I am trying to send an email to the user on signup. I don't want the user to be waiting for the email to be sent. So I am trying to queue the event and return back to the user as soon as possible.

Comment: Then you're looking for another type of queues: [Message Queues](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues) which allow you to execute code independent of the current request. They do need additional services to work which you can either [install on your server](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) or use as a [remote service](http://www.iron.io/mq).

Comment: If you want a quick way to get queues up and running here's a video explaining how to do that using [IronMQ](http://vimeo.com/64703617).

Comment: I know about the Message Queues. But it requires my project to be deployed in remote server. I am working locally and the `Event::fire` works just fine for the project I am working on but I thought it would be cool to implement the queue feature. :D
So tell me if `Event::queue` and `Event::flush` works locally and how do I achieve that. If not, I will go on with `Event::fire`.

Comment: The Event Queues in Laravel do not use background workers as Message Queues do to execute code asynchronously, so you can't achieve what you want using Event Queues (neither locally nor on your production server). However as I pointed out in my previous comments the IronMQ service is a remote service which means you can use it both while developing locally and on your production server.

Comment: I have watched a video on IronMQ before, correct me if I am wrong but doesn't it need the production url registered as the subscriber url in [iron.io](http://www.iron.io)? It can't hit/ping my local url when it executes the queues.

Comment: You are indeed right about needing to specify a queue URL, I did miss that. However, in your local dev enviroment you can set the queue driver to `sync` and use the `iron` driver only in production (where it actually matters for the email to be deferred to a background worker).

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions. I was interested to know if I could achieve the asynchronous event queue in local development. It seems that is not possible and so my actual question is answered.
But now how do I accept your answer? :D
P.S this is my first post in stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi  @Shhetri  , have you moved to the Queue instead of Event::queue I am facing the same issue. please let me know does the Event::queue is work?